# Ensure program loads below 4 GB using --image-base in Linux

Tags: linux, linker

I'm trying to ensure a particular binary loads within 4 GB of physical memory. In the LD options I see --image-base. The documentation says:
[This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

On Linux, if I use this option, it says unrecognized option '--image-base'.

Is there any way we can ensure a particular binary is loaded below 4 GB on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to ensure a particular binary loads within 4 GB of physical memory.

Assuming you are talking about user-level (application) code, and not about the Linux kernel, you can ensure *nothing* about *physical* memory. You can only ensure something about *virtual* memory.

Your question also makes no sense if you are using 32-bit system, as *all* memory is below 4GB on such system.

Therefore, your question appears to be: "how do I link an executable on a 64-bit Linux system, so that it loads below `0x100000000`?"

Assuming you are using `x86_64` the answer is: default link options will *already* do that for main executable (though not for shared libraries), so you don't need to do anything special. If you want *all* code to be loaded under 4GB boundary, link your application with `-static` flag (but beware: doing this may not work for a variety of reasons, and imposes license restrictions on your binary as well).

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific in the type of program or the type of architecture. Here are some more details:

1. I'm trying to load a kernel module (driver) under 4 GB physical memory.

2. I'm trying this on a 32-bit PAE kernel where the module load address can be between 4 GB to 5 GB (although system has 4GB). This is done by BIOS for remapping of memory from 3 GB to 4 GB.